# How can I move files into an zip archive from a batfile?

Tags: batch-file, archive

I think the header explain the question. 
I want to do inside a bat-file:

```
zip /a /m myfile.log myarchive.zip
```

where I just invented the zip comand and the options:
/a add file
/m Move file

It is run on Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use an actual implementation of a zip program.  take a look at gzip, bzip or 7zip.  Each program will have different command line switches

Answer (score 2):

I've used 7-Zip in batch files, this line for example compresses all *.bak files in a given folder:

```
FOR /f %%i in ('DIR /b D:\Backup\*.bak') DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tbzip2 -mx3 D:\BackupCompressed\%%i.7z D:\Backup\SQLDaily\%%i
```

You have to [download the right version of 7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) for your operating system (32 or 64 bit and use the 7z.exe).

Here is the link to a page [with command line examples](http://dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples).